# Travelling to Macedonia with German Resident Permit

Tags: indian-citizens, macedonia

Me and my wife traveling to Macedonia next week. I am an Indian, holding a Permanent Resident Permit in Germany but my wife still has a one year resident permit. Does she need to apply for visa?

Comment: How does your wife permit look like? Is it a plastic card with her photo, just like yours, only with different wording? What do you call a permanent resident permit btw, is it a *Niederlassungserlaubnis*?

Comment: It is exactly like mine, just the difference is she has limited period resident permit (1 year) and mine is unlimited.

Comment: My RP: Valid Till (Gültig bis): Unbefristet and Art des Titels: Niederlassungserlaubnis.

My wife: Valid Till (Gültig bis): 09-06-2016 and Art des Titels: Aufenthaltserlaubnis

Comment: Hopefully someone who has actually been there on such a document will be able to confirm and post an answer but she should be just fine. The things I read just mention regular residence permits and that's what an Aufenthaltserlaubnis is. It's already one step up from a visa (and some of those are accepted too), demanding a permanent residence permit would be very restrictive indeed.

Comment: @Relaxed the comments on the answer seem to indicate that even though a temporary residence permit is logically between a visa and a permanent residence permit, unlike those two documents it does not excuse the higher from the visa requirement.

Comment: @phoog I hadn't noticed this last time I looked into it but I am still unconvinced. The English on the website is very poor and, unlike say in the US, “permanent stay” isn't a well defined status across the EU. It would be awfully difficult for Macedonian border guards to sort out who has a permanent right to stay or not. FWIW (which is not much obviously), the word “permanent” is also absent from the Google translated version of the Macedonian original. I strongly suspect what is meant by that is simply a common format residence permit.

Comment: @Relaxed from the comments below: *Falls sie indischen Pass hat und aufenthalt bis 09.06.2016 dann ihre Frau braucht unbedingt ein Visa für Macedonien.* "if she has an Indian passport and residence until 09.06.2016 then your wife absolutely needs a visa for Macedonia."

Comment: @phoog OK, I see.

Answer (score 0):

[Ministry of Foreign Affairs:](http://www.mfa.gov.mk/index.php/en/for-foreign-nationals/information-on-visa-entry-to-the-republic-of-macedonia/entry-in-the-republic-of-macedonia-for-schengen-visa-holders)

> 1. EU member countries and signatories of the Schengen Agreement
>      •have the right to enter the Republic of Macedonia with a valid ID card.
> 2. Third countries with permanent stay in an EU member country or signatory country of the Schengen Agreement
>      •may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.
> 3. Third countries with multiple entry short stay Schengen visa type C valid at least 5 (five) days beyond the intended stay in the Republic of Macedonia.
>      •may stay in the Republic of Macedonia for up to 15 (fifteen) days upon every entry to the territory of the Republic of Macedonia, and the total amount of the subsequent stays in the Republic of Macedonia must not be longer than 3 (three) months within a six-months period, starting from the date of the first entry.

So if you have a **Permanent** resident permit, you can travel to Macedonia for 15 days, however, unless you have a Schengen visa Type C, you can not enter the country without a Permanent resident permit.

Comment: Ya this I read this on their website.

I called up Auslanderbehörde to check whether my wife has Schengen C or D type they said Schengen C or D type is issued only for 3 months and Resident permit is one step higher then Schengen C or D which is issued for 1 year.

So my question is when they allow people with Schengen C or D type, then why not for a Resident permit.

Last year we had been to Croatia which is also not in Schengen, we could go in without any problem. 
Craotia is also a former part of Yugoslavia.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Addy check out the question link I sent under the question as duplicate. There it mentions that someone who studies in Germany (Student Visa/Temporary Permit) went to Macedonia, however were refused entry.

Comment: yes I went through it, but my wife is not on a Student visa, i suppose its a dependent visa.

Comment: Student visa is basically the equivalent of temporary resident visa.

Comment: I would like to share few information which I got from Macedonian Embassy Berlin it might be helpful for someone in the future.

"Die Frage ist noch, sie haben indischen reisepass und haben unbefristet in Deutschland, aber was für ein Reisepass hat ihre Frau auch indischen oder..?

Falls sie indischen Poass hat und aufenthalt bis 09.06.2016 dann ihre Frau braucht unbedingt ein Visa für Macedonien."

Thank you.

Comment: This email from Macedonian Embassy Munich.

"
Falls sie einen unbefristeten aufenthalt in Deutschland besitzen können sie sich bis zu 15 Tagen in Mazedonien Visumfrei aufhalten.

Falls sie eine Schengen MULTI Viza haben , dürfen sie sich ebenfalls bis zu 15 Tagen in MK aufhalten ."

Comment: @1234, you have an *unlimited* (unbefristeten) residence permit and can enter, while your wife has a *temporary* residence permit and needs a visa.

Comment: yes exactly. I dont think I would have a problem but my wife cannot enter without visa.

Comment: @1234 Croatia is, like Macedonia, formerly part of Yugoslavia, and not part of the Schengen area, but unlike Macedonia it is part of the EU and is in the process of joining the Schengen area, so it's not unlikely that the rules around recognizing documents from Schengen countries would be different.